# set union operation in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to get the 'set union' of two closed paths in tikz?

To show what I mean, consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=cyan] (0,1)--(3,1)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
    \path[fill=orange] (1,0)--(1,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to take the two paths and obtain from them a single path that encloses the union of the red path and the blue one. In this example, that would correspond to the black line below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=cyan] (0,1)--(3,1)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
    \path[fill=orange] (1,0)--(1,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--cycle;
    \path[draw,line width=1.5pt] (0,1)--(1,1)--(1,0)--(2,0)--(2,1)--(3,1)--(3,2)--(2,2)--(2,3)--(1,3)--(1,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but of course I want to get it automatically, for any pair of paths.

Answer (score 9):

It's not completely automatic (you have to select the 'parts'), but you can achieve that using `spath3` and `intersections` Ti*k*Z libraries.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[fill=cyan  ,spath/save=A] (0,1)--(3,1)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
    \path[fill=orange,spath/save=B] (1,0)--(1,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--cycle;
% spath3 operatios
\tikzset
{
  spath/split at intersections={A}{B},
  spath/get components of={A}\Acpts,
  spath/get components of={B}\Bcpts
}
% the set union:
\draw[thick,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Acpts{4},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{4},reverse,weld},
     ] -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]